How can i add multiple seekbars for a video that is divided into multiple parts
I have a video divided into multiple parts (each part's duration is about 5 minutes). When i am playing these parts in Exoplayer with addMediaItems(), all parts are playing perfectly but everytime whenever a video part is playing, seekbar is getting initialised from 0 and each time video's total duration showing is the duration of the current video part that is playing.
I want to get the total time of all the video parts added in playlist and show a single seekbar for total playlist.
If i want to show multiple seekbars each for a part and combined them horizontally. Can this is possible?

You can use a single Slider to control all the videos duration. Here is a simple approach:
Get Total video's currently in playlist: player.mediaItemCount ( example: returns 10).
Since every video is of 5 minutes so total time = 50 minutes = 30,00,000 ms
// Language : kotlin , Framework : Jetpack Compose
var totalDuration = 3000000L
var currentVideo = 0
var input = player.duration



Slider(
                value = input/ videoDuration,
                onValueChange = { },
                enabled = true,
                valueRange = 0f..1f
            )



Inside onValueChange = {} do this calculation:

val toSeek : Double = it*videoDuration / 3,00,000
currentVideo = toSeek


if(currentVideo == toSeek.toInt) {
       
      player.seekTo((toSeek-currentVideo)*1,00,000))
}else{

      player.seekTo(currentVideo,(toSeek-currentVideo)*1,00,000)

}




Convert The HardCoded Values to parameterized variables.
You can increase the performance by converting the Long  values to Int.
